Send Feedback buttons in Message Templates in Whatsapp API

I want to know how can we add thumbs up and thumbs down feedback buttons(Refer in image below message container) for Whatsapp Messages sent via whatsapp APIs using the message template
I have explored all the provided templates in Whatsapp Manager or even created custom templates but couldn't find a way to achieve the same.
Please help.
